# IIS Express won't serve from custom domain

Tags: iis-express

Here is my setup of ACL list, IIS Express binding, Visual Studio Web setting...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But it doesn't work. What's the next thing to try?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work"

Comment: http://bf:55438 doesn't access the server.

Comment: Have you set up DNS or simply hosts file?

Comment: No I haven't. I need to do that yes?

Comment: I'm running Windows on a Mac. So I either set up a DNS or edit the hosts file on both operating systems?

Comment: Done that and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @IanWarburton, post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `127.0.0.1 bf` to the OS' `host` file.